# IIS Rewrite to a new port - Different IIS version, different results

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

A server (x.com) has the following parameters:
 - It is accessible from the outside from port 80.
 - It has an internal service running on port 1000.
 - The service needs to be accessible from a subdomain (service.x.com)

Running IIS on Windows 10, I did the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="URL Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:1000/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And it worked beautifully.

The same code, on the other end, run on Windows Server 2012 R2 yields this:

HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x8007007b

I do not understand why it works on one version of IIS and not on the other one.

Answer (score 3):

I found: ARR (Application Request Routing) needs to be enable.
Of course, this is not mentioned anywhere in any of the error messages nor in log.